# How to access the server variables from any route in NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to get `server` declared in the main.js of my app (very simple):

```
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running")
})
```

And use it in another route file. This is for SocketIO so I can do the following:

```
const SocketIO = require("socket.io")
const io = SocketIO.listen(server)

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new connection at: ", socket.id)
})
```

Is it possible to do `module.exports` of the main.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another js file in the same directory of main.js and in this file :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running")
})

module.exports = server;
```

In your main.js file include this js file. For now, say this file name is test.js.

```
const server = require('./test');
```

To include this in your routes file just do another require statement with the appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this answers your question:

```
//Dependencies
const express = require('express');

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3005;

//Initialize the App
const app = express();

//Start the app with socket io;
const io = require('socket.io')(app.listen(port, () => {
    appLog.info(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
}));

//Export the module here
module.exports = { io };


//Make sure to load the routes that will be using socket io
//after the exports, so that the socket io is properly exported
//before it's being used in the routes

//Load Routes
const exampleRoute= require('./routes/exampleRoute');

//Use Routes
app.use('/', exampleRoute);
```